# Prove that the system has no closed trajectories in the quadrant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the plane autonomous system

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = X(x,y) = x(2-x)-y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = Y(x,y) = y-kx$$

for $k>2$. Using Bendixson-Dulac Theorem, prove that the system has no closed trajectories in the quadrant $x,y\geq0$.

I have tried the following

$$(\phi X)_{x} + (\phi Y)_{y} = x^2(-\phi_x)+y(-\phi x+\phi_y) + x(2\phi _x-k\phi_y-2\phi)+3\phi$$

but I can't find a suitable $\phi$ such that the expression is $>0$ or $<0$. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something quadratic, like $ax^2 + by^2$? This is usually a go-to method for similar problems.

Comment: Hi, not really. The form is really strange and I don't think quadratic fits well here.

Comment: Well if you haven't really checked that out I still suggest to do this. By the way the absence of closed trajectories can be shown without using Dulac-Bendixson (if you allowed to use the fact that there is always an equilibrium inside the domain enclosed by closed trajectory).